# Why `(require 'my-package)' is not evaluated from within a `defun' form?

Tags: require

I have an `init.el` file with the following line:
`(require 'my-1)`

The `my-1` package is on the load path.

The `my-1` defines this function:

```
(defun my-f ()
  "Hello."
  (interactive)
  (when (featurep 'my-2) (require 'my-2)
    ... some code here ...)
```

'my-2' is also on the load path.

Now the problem: calling `my-f` works (i.e. Emacs evaluates the `my-1` package), but the feature `my-2` is not loaded. If I manually evaluated `(require 'my-2)` - everything works (this also proves that `my-2` package is on the load path).

How do I `require` `my-2` package from within the `defun` so it gets evaluated?

Comment: Can you show complete code? As it stands, the `when` will test if `my-2` is a feature (i.e. if the `my-2` package is already loaded): If it is, it will require it again (which is a no-op) and do the rest of the code; if it is not, then none of that will be done: not the `require` and not the `some code here` either.

Comment: Maybe you want `(when (not (featurep 'my-2)) (require 'my-2) ...)`?

Comment: @NickD: `(require 'my-2)` is the same as `(when (not (featurep 'my-2)) (require 'my-2))`.

Comment: Just put `(require 'my-2)` in your function. Remove the test for its feature. If its feature is present then it's already been loaded, so `require` would be a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`featurep` is true when the specified feature has *already* been provided, and so this code doesn't make sense:

```el
(when (featurep 'my-2)
  (require 'my-2)
  ...)
```

That `require` and `...` can only be evaluated if `my-2` had *previously* been loaded by some other means.  So the `require` either (a) isn't called, or (b) is called redundantly and does nothing.

You most likely want either:

```el
(when (require 'my-2 nil t)
  ...)
```

Or:

```el
(require 'my-2 nil t)
(when (featurep 'my-2)
  ...)
```

You might prefer the latter case if `my-2` was used pervasively throughout the library and was *expected* to be present -- in which case the `require` might be at the beginning of the library, and individual functions would then only need the `featurep` check.

n.b. I've assumed you don't want `require` to signal an error if it can't load `my-2`, as it seems like an optional dependency for your code in general.

Use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to see details of `require` or `featurep`, and see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Loading` for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, my intention to use `when` was to avoid: 1) errors if the `my-2` was not available and 2) to 'lazy load' the `my-2` - to speed-up load time, by not requiring it during the start-up. Any idea how to approach the 2)?

Comment: If you're putting the `require` in the function(s) which use it, then it's not loaded before it's needed.